# Draw the same circle on the same image on two different devices (different screen density)

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view, android-screen

I have an image on two different devices with different screen size and density.

Using a canvas, I want to draw a circle on device A image, then send the center coordinates to device B, and draw the circle in the same position, even if the same image has a different size.

What I do on device A before sending the the x coordinate is the following:

```
float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int width = getWidth();
float inchesLength = width/density;
float scaledXCenter = xCenter / inchesLength;
```

I do the same for the y coordinate.

On device B, I get the same parameters and multiply the received coordinate for the inchesLenght:

```
float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int width = getWidth();
float inchesLength = width/density;
float restoredXCenter = scaledXCenter * inchesLength;
```

I am testing this on AVDs.
The problem is that each AVD has a screen density of 1, even if I can clearly see that on the smaller device (device A), the same image is fully displayed, but occupies a smaller space!

Should this approach work when working on real devices?

Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find the width and height of the canvas and by dividing width and height find a ratio. This ratio should be multiplied with each value

Here is the sample code

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class GameCanvas extends View {
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private float canvasWidth;
    private float canvasHeight;
    private float ratio;

    public GameCanvas(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvasWidth = canvas.getWidth();
        canvasHeight = canvas.getHeight();
        ratio=canvasWidth/canvasHeight;

        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        //canvas.drawRect(30*ratio, 30*ratio, 100*ratio, 200*ratio, paint);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
        paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        canvas.drawRect(33*ratio, 60*ratio, 77*ratio, 77*ratio, paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        canvas.drawRect(33*ratio, 33*ratio, 77*ratio, 60*ratio, paint);

    }
}
```